# Force resolution of only specific versions of a library?

Tags: javascript, security, npm, yarnpkg

I have packages transitively referencing [minimatch](https://www.npmjs.com/package/minimatch) versions 3.0.4 and 5.0.1. Version 3.0.4 reportedly has a vulnerability. I would like to force the resolution of minimatch 3.0.4 to perhaps 3.0.6 or 3.0.7, but leave minimatch 5.0.1 as-is. So I would end up referencing 3.0.6 and 5.0.1.

Is there a way to achieve this via package.json with yarn (1.22)? I see [you can do](https://classic.yarnpkg.com/lang/en/docs/selective-version-resolutions/):

```js
resolutions: {
  "minimatch": "3.0.6"
}
```

But this would redirect all versions of minimatch to 3.0.6, not just 3.0.4.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like this is possible with newer versions of yarn (https://yarnpkg.com/cli/set/resolution), however, I'm on yarn "classic" where such support was considered ["too advanced"](https://github.com/yarnpkg/rfcs/blob/master/implemented/0000-selective-versions-resolutions.md#mapping-version-specifications).

While I could not specify what I wanted, I could find the exact dependency chain using 3.0.4 and specify that in resolutions. e.g.

`"react-scripts/react-dev-utils/recursive-readdir/minimatch": "^3.0.5"`

This solved the problem.